# Retrieve index of 'i' in for loop, Python, Django-QuerySet

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, django-queryset

I've got two model objects inside of a query set

```
x = [<model.object>]
y = [<model.object>]
```

I need to process each object through a script for each of the sets

```
for i in [x,y]:
    i.attribute_1
    i.attribute_2
```

This wont work though because in this example 'i' is going to represent a query set not an object

```
for i in [x,y]:
    i[0].attribute_1
    i[0].attribute_2
```

Seems cumbersome

```
for i in [x[0],y[0]]:
    i.attribute_1
    i.attribute_2
```

Same problem

```
for i[0] in [x,y]:
    i.attribute_1
    i.attribute_2
```

Doesnt work.

Is there a better soloution than

```
for i in [x,y]:
    i = i[0]
    i.attribute_1
    i.attribute_2
```

?
Or better yet

```
z = 0
for i in [x,y]:
    i = i[z]
    i.attribute_1
    i.attribute_2
    z += 1
```

?
Thanks :)

Comment: How did you get the querysets in the first place? Maybe there's a way of getting both objects in one.

Comment: I just filtered the results from a database (two different ones) I think I'm better off with them in two sets for easier comparison?

Comment: I wish you'd show the code. Apart from anything else, if you know you're only going to get one result from each query, why don't you use `get()` instead of `filter()`? That way you'll just get two objects, rather than two querysets.

Comment: I need them in query sets so i can use the values() method get the dictionarys out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have it

```
for i in [x,y]:
    z = 0
        while z < len(i)
        o = i[z]
        o.attribute_1
        o.attribute_2
        z += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do here is:

```
for index, pair in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
   current_x, current_y = pair
   # do stuff with index, current_x, current_y ...
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but I don't think that's quite what I'm looking for in this case

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `itertools.chain` applies best for this case:

```
for i in itertools.chain(x, y):
    i.attr_1
    i.attr_2
```

It can also be applied to situation, where you have a list of query sets, like that:

```
query_sets = [[<model.object>, <model.object>], [<model.object>, <model.object>, <model.object>], ....]
for i in itertools.chain(*query_sets):
    ....
```